# How to convert an unsigned char variable that holds two hexadecimal values into two chars with one hex number

Tags: c++

I need to get the hash (sha1) value of a given unsigned char array. So, I have used openssl. The SHA1 function generate the hash value in an unsigned char array which has 20 values. Indeed each value represent two hexadecimal values.

But, I should convert the generated array (with length of 20) to an array of chars with 40 values.

For example now hashValue[0] is "a0" but, I want to have hashValue[0] = "a" and hashValue[1] = "0"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/sha.h> // For sha1

using namespace std; 

int main() {

    unsigned char plainText[] = "compute sha1";
    unsigned char hashValue[20];

    SHA1(plainText,sizeof(plainText),hashValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x", hashValue[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another array and use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or safer [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to print into it instead of the standard output.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h> // For sha1

using namespace std; 

int main() {

    unsigned char plainText[] = "compute sha1";
    unsigned char hashValue[20];
    char output[41];

    SHA1(plainText,sizeof(plainText),hashValue);

    char *c_output = output;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++, c_output += 2) {
        snprintf(c_output, 3, "%02x", hashValue[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Now `output[0] == 'a'` and `output[1] == '0'`.

There might be other, even better solution, this is just the first that comes to mind.

EDIT: Added fix from comments.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want to separate the high order and low order bytes.

to isolate the high order byte, shift right 4 bytes.
and to isolate the low order byte, apply a mask. AND with 0x0f

```
int x = 0x3A;
int y = x >> 4;   // get high order nibble
int z = x & 0x0F; // get low order nibble
printf("%02x\n", x);
printf("%02x\n", y);
printf("%02x\n", z);
```

Comment: Er, no. OP doesn't want to do that,.

Comment: Yes, I should read more about it. But, it looks snprintf() make it easier.